# Removing a formula from a spreadsheet that creates a date every time a new row is made in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

On excel, a coworker created a formula that copies a date from one column to the next every time a new row is made. If no date is entered, the other cell in the next column will show 0-JAN-1900 as defult. We no longer need this formula and it has become a bother but we do not know how to get rid of it. Does any one have any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

How does that "formula" look then? i.e. if it is an actual formula, present in the cell with the date, then just select the cell and hit `Delete`.

Otherwise it probably is a few lines of VBA (Hit `Alt`+`F11` - to see all of that).

There is a special function/sub **name** that will cause THAT function to be executed on new entries in a spreadsheet (now if I'd only could remember the name ;.).

Comment: CTRL-F11 => Alt-F11  *(Hard to get everything correct when having no Excel available ;-)*

Answer (score 0):

What you describe COULD be occurring with a cell formula, one that like `Hannu` says can be removed with a simple `Delete` or as it sounds like it is a whole column of unhappy formulas (if it is a formula at all), then deleting the column (so long as the column does not have other things above or below this data region, things which you'd want to keep, in which case just a bit tougher).

One could have a much more complicated "cell-side" formula that updates both cells via, say, old-style array formulas or the newer dynamic functionality (`Spill`). But that would pretty much have to use the functionality that allows circularity and so seems very, very unlikely. Even then though, editing the cell the formula is in could fix things nicely but we cannot advise how since we do not see the formula in the question.

That leaves work done in a macro as the most likely candidate as one could easily do this, and formulas that are not clearly delete-able cannot, and because the way you describe it feels like you cannot actually see this "formula." As `Hannu` says, that can be looked for. And unless there are lots of other things like this, it may be about the only thing there and so easily deleted.

However, the shortcut to use is `Alt-F11`! Do NOT use `Ctrl-F11` which creates "macro sheets" of the sort that Excel used back in the 80's and part of the 90's. Before they created VBA. It doesn't seem very possible one of those was used.

Answer (score 0):

Select the Row and click Delete in keyboard.